SmsRetrieverHelper : SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token app not Recognized by PlayStore
I am getting this error when I am sending otp to any phone number. I wanted to automatically login the user when he receive the OTP but not able to do.
Error :- "E/FirebaseAuth(16666): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token; app not Recognized by Play Store.
D/FirebaseAuth(16666): Re-triggering phone verification with Recaptcha flow forced for phone number +919068616413
I/zza (16666): ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = true, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false"
firebase_auth: ^5.3.0
firebase_core: ^3.5.0
Important:
I've set up Firebase "Phone Authentication" in Firebase Console & App
I've uploaded the app in playstore too and also set up those SHA keys in Firebase Console.
I've set up SHA Keys (Debug & Release) in Firebase Console
